# git oddity; local modified images are not used on production after deployment ( not updated )

Tags: git, deployment

I have the strange issue that certain images from my webapp are not updated when I deploy my app with rails. The old images are still there.

What would be a good way to check if my git repo has all the changes available?

Normally ill do git commit . -m 'fixes'
git add .
and use a gitignore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with [git-ls-files](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-ls-files.html)

In your case: `git ls-files public/` to return a list of files under git.
Compare that with `git ls-files public -o` to list all other files, such as files that are ignored or files that are not (yet) in the index.

Also, just a simple [`git status`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-status.html) will show what files are staged, unstaged, untracked and so on.

Comment: Thanks, still strange but after manually adding the files with git add /path/to/file.jpg it seems to work okay. the git ls-files was great dident knew about that one