# Images in public folder are not updated while deploying on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have a strange issue while deploying to Heroku.
Since a few days ago, it seems that when I deploy, my modified images are not updated on Heroku.

The process is this one :

- I modify the image (like the size)
- I commit the modification
- I push on Heroku
- I try to load the image ->  **not updated**
- I run `heroku run bash` to witness the file on public/ folder -> **not updated**, still with the old size
- As with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12355605/git-oddity-local-modified-images-are-not-used-on-production-after-deployment), `git ls-files public -o` shows nothing out of place

  - I checked on github, my file is well updated in my repo -> *not a git problem*

I duplicated an image an named it diferently : it is loaded on the repo. I then deleted it : **still on the repo**.

So I guess it's a cache issue. Therefore I tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29306089/2726340) to purge the assetscache... with no luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Run the command:

```
heroku run rake assets:clean
```

If it doesn't work, then run the following command:

```
heroku run rake assets:precompile
```